# How to define controller(s) for many templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am using angular routes  like

```
$routeProvider

        .when('/problems/monthly/volume',{
                templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth.htm',
                controller: 'mainController'

        })
```

and so on .When i have many templateUrl and i am usinf one controller all of them , is it necessary to define `controller: 'mainController'`  for all of them ? if no where is this one point where i can define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you gave controller name in index.html file, then no need of mentioning controller name in $rootProvider. not even for single. you can write like this.

```
$routeProvider

    .when('/problems/monthly/volume',{
            templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth.htm'

    })

    .when('/problems/monthly/volume1',{
            templateUrl: 'example.htm'

    })

   .when('/problems/monthly/volume2',{
            templateUrl: 'example2.htm'

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to write multiple routes with the same controller name

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/problems/monthly/volume',{
                templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth.htm',
                controller: 'mainController'

        })
     .when('/problems/monthly/volume2',{
                templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth2.htm',
                controller: 'mainController'

        }) .when('/problems/monthly/volume3',{
                templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth3.htm',
                controller: 'mainController'

        })
```

and so On

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one controller for more page you can add this controller into the HTML code.
For example

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
...
</div>
```

And then insert the view of different template into the div.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
<ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

while configuring the route no need to mention controller name

```
$routeProvider
.when('/problems/monthly/volume',{
                templateUrl: 'frivolousTerminalsPersentByMonth.htm',
        })
```